# Sections with unusual borders

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I recently ran into a PSD template that has an unusual border with triangles. I know how to create triangles by itself using pure CSS, but the question is (just for interest) about this images:

[image: Example one]
[image: Example two]

Are these created just by a background that is already cut like this, or can I do it using the same CSS?

Comment: They can be created with CSS, SVG, Canvas or using an image depending on the needs.

Comment: The question is if you can?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which this shape could be achieved. Using `clip-path`, CSS triangles, SVG, Canvas and image backgrounds are some of them. Each method has their own pros and cons. We cannot suggest one without knowing your needs fully. You should choose the method which fits your needs the best. Generally I **would suggest using SVG** to create such complex paths/shapes.

Below are a couple of sample snippets for creating this with CSS and SVG `clip-path` feature. It is not 100% exactly as you want it to be but I would leave the fine tuning part to you.

You would also need to adjust the content position such that part of it also doesn't get clipped. In the snippet I have used `padding-top` to achieve this. You can use other methods like positioning also.

---

**Using CSS:**

Using CSS `clip-path`, you can create a polygonal path and clip the element into the required shape. The main drawback of this approach would be [the poor browser support for CSS clip-paths](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). Currently only Webkit powered browsers support the CSS `clip-path` feature.

```css
.unusual-border{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  background: rgb(74,139, 207);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 40% 5%, 55% 20%, 60% 15%, 75% 25%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%, 40% 5%, 55% 20%, 60% 15%, 75% 25%, 100% 10%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

/* Just for demo */
body{
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/abstract/1);
}
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="unusual-border">Some content</div>
```

---

**Using SVG:**

SVG `clip-path` is very similar in working to the CSS version except that it has much better browser support than its CSS counterpart.

```css
.unusual-border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 10%;
  background: rgb(74, 139, 207);
  -webkit-clip-path: url("#unusual-border");
  clip-path: url("#unusual-border");
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/400/abstract/1);
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="unusual-border" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="M0,0.25 0.4,0.05 0.55,0.2 0.6,0.15 0.75,0.25 1,0.1 1,1 0,1z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="unusual-border">Some content</div>
```

**Note:** Clip paths (either version) are not supported in IE. If you wish to support IE then you can use pure SVG path element (not `clipPath`) to create the background image (or) use an image (or) use complex CSS transformations with multiple elements. I would **certainly not recommend using CSS transformations** and multiple elements.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you *could* build something like that using pure CSS3, but that doesn't mean that it's a good idea.

More than likely, the template uses transparent PNG images which are defined as the `background-image` to the section's `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. Another option may be the use of `<canvas>`, or SVG.

Of course, without seeing the markup and CSS, it's almost impossible to say for certain how this designer has handled it. And of course you could have quite easily checked the source code to find the answer yourself...

Comment: No problem checking the source code. The only problem is that the current example is a PSD template :)