# how do i go about making cone shaped section borders in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

How would you go about creating a section like below: ?

[image]

See hwo the banner has borders that are cone shaped , now earlir when i'd have a need for something like that i have tried and worked with stuff like below:

```
<div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 120px;
    right: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    -o-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateZ(-5deg);
    z-index: -1;
    background: red;
}
```

But i am not sure if using this same trick would be good in this instance as that cone shape needs to be there at all widths and that design needs to be the same on all devices.

So how do i go about making cone shaped section borders in CSS ?

Comment: I'd recommend using SVG (`path` or `clipPath` or `mask`). You would get some ideas from this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443763/how-to-accomplish-this-shape-with-angled-cuts-at-the-bottom-and-an-image-backgro/35449133#35449133 (it has a cut only on one side).

Comment: Have you seen this? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/  Using that technique, you could position these triangles so they overlay a traditional rectangular area of content. You could simply use Media Queries to create custom sizes for various viewports.

Comment: @Harry thanks let me go through it :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus old trick , i am not going to use that . thanks though !

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do it is by making it a `background-image` and aligning it to the top of a div. Probably not the best way to go about it, but if all else fails, why not?